# Dropdownlist data items displayed in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, javascript, html

How can I get the list of data items displayed in alphabetical order in Drop down? I used the OderBy and I did not get the results I wanted...plz help.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [CompanyID], [Company] FROM [Company]  ORDER BY [CompanyID], [Company] DESC">
<SelectParameters>
```

Comment: just do order by  [Company] ASC

Answer (score 2):

Order by `Company` first:

```
ORDER BY [Company], [CompanyID]
```

---

You're currently ordering by `CompanyID` (which I assume is a primary key integer), and then `Company DESC`. This means it will order the records by the numerical `CompanyID`, then any which are matching (which I doubt would), would then be ordered by the Company Name, Z-A.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY [Company], [CompanyID] ASC
```

Comment: `ASC` is default, you don't need to specify it

Answer (score 0):

should be order by company name... so

```
SELECT  * FROM Table ORDER BY Company
```